# Heap deallocation profiling

Tags: c++, memory-management, valgrind, memory-profiling, massif

valgrind's `massif` tool is able to give me points in my code (including call stacks) where data is *allocated*.

E.g.

```
99.97% (3,775,782,255B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->51.05% (1,928,081,040B) 0x37E712: MyFunc() (my_file.h:49)
| ->51.05% (1,928,081,040B) 0x37E15A: AnotherFunc() (my_file.cpp:213)
...
```

Instead of getting these statistics for malloc/new, is it possible to get it for free/delete instead?

I.e. is tracking deallocations possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you sure `massif` is the tool you need to fulfill your goal?

Comment: Deallocation functions are typically quite trivial compared to allocation functions, what could be the reason to profile them?

Comment: I have two patches, which allocate the same amount of memory. But one of them is having a much lower memory peak, so it is freeing memory during the execution - somewhere. And I want to figure out where and when the memory is freed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track deallocation using e.g. memcheck and the option --xtree-memory=full.

See e.g. https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#opt.xtree-memory
and https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.xtree
for more information.